# Dot product between 2D and 3D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Assume that I have two arrays `V` and `Q`, where `V` is `(i, j, j)` and `Q` is `(j, j)`. I now wish to compute the dot product of `Q` with each "row" of `V` and save the result as an `(i, j, j)` sized matrix. This is easily done using for-loops by simply iterating over `i` like

```
import numpy as np

v = np.random.normal(size=(100, 5, 5))
q = np.random.normal(size=(5, 5))
output = np.zeros_like(v)

for i in range(v.shape[0]):
    output[i] = q.dot(v[i])
```

However, this is way too slow for my needs, and I'm guessing there is a way to vectorize this operation using either `einsum` or `tensordot`, but I haven't managed to figure it out. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), but need to swap axes afterwards, like so -

```
out = np.tensordot(v,q,axes=(1,1)).swapaxes(1,2)
```

With [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), it's a bit more straight-forward, like so -

```
out = np.einsum('ijk,lj->ilk',v,q)
```